# Why on dynamically created canvas context does not work?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Look: http://jsfiddle.net/MrHIDEn/QYL3t/

This code draws 3 boxes Reg,Green,Blue but context("2d") from Blue does do nothing. Why?

HTML:

```
<div id="divR">
<canvas id="cvsR" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="divG"></div>
<div id="divB"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var cvsR = document.getElementById("cvsR");
var ctxR = cvsR.getContext("2d");
ctxR.fillStyle = "red";
ctxR.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 75);

var divG = document.getElementById("divG");
divG.innerHTML = '<canvas id="cvsG" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid green"></canvas>';
var cvsG = document.getElementById("cvsG");
var ctxG = cvsG.getContext("2d");
ctxG.fillStyle = "green";
ctxG.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 75);

// Dynamiclly
var divB = document.getElementById("divB");
var cvsB = document.createElement("canvas");
cvsB.width = 100;
cvsB.height = 100;
cvsB.style.border = "1px solid blue";
cvsB.id = "cvsB";
var ctxB = cvsB.getContext("2d");
ctxB.fillStyle = "blue";
ctxB.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 75);
divB.innerHTML = cvsB.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't even run, it craps out on the console clear part `Illegal invocation`

Comment: Ok, i removed that part. Sorry. It was for test and works for me. Any way it is updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here `divB.innerHTML = cvsB.outerHTML;`, with this code you aren't adding the canvas `cvsB` to divB but a can vas with the same html as `cvsB`. To add `cvsB` to the div just append it

```
divB.appendChild(cvsB);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QYL3t/14/

Comment: That is perfect. I did not know 'appendChild' function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would append the canvas before reading the context, but it works without this, so this is just my personal preference:

```
cvsB.id = "cvsB";
divB.appendChild(cvsB);
var ctxB = cvsB.getContext("2d");
ctxB.fillStyle = "blue";
ctxB.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 75);
```